# Implementing pthread barrier for Mac OS/X

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written this [little thingie](https://github.com/ademakov/DarwinPthreadBarrier) to fix a problem of missing `pthread_barrier_t` in Mac OS/X pthreads. Are there any issues with this code?

The header:

```
#ifndef PTHREAD_BARRIER_H
#define PTHREAD_BARRIER_H

#include <pthread.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if !defined(PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)
# define PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD  (1)
#endif

#if !defined(PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE)
# define PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE    (42)
#endif
#if !defined(PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)
# define PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED     (43)
#endif

typedef struct {
} pthread_barrierattr_t;

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    unsigned int limit;
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int phase;
} pthread_barrier_t;

int pthread_barrierattr_init(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr);
int pthread_barrierattr_destroy(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr);

int pthread_barrierattr_getpshared(const pthread_barrierattr_t *restrict attr,
                   int *restrict pshared);
int pthread_barrierattr_setpshared(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr,
                   int pshared);

int pthread_barrier_init(pthread_barrier_t *restrict barrier,
             const pthread_barrierattr_t *restrict attr,
             unsigned int count);
int pthread_barrier_destroy(pthread_barrier_t *barrier);

int pthread_barrier_wait(pthread_barrier_t *barrier);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __APPLE__ */

#endif /* PTHREAD_BARRIER_H */
```

The source file:

```
#include "pthread_barrier.h"

#include <errno.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__

#define __unused __attribute__((unused))

int
pthread_barrierattr_init(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr __unused)
{
    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrierattr_destroy(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr __unused)
{
    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrierattr_getpshared(const pthread_barrierattr_t *restrict attr __unused,
                   int *restrict pshared)
{
    *pshared = PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE;
    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrierattr_setpshared(pthread_barrierattr_t *attr __unused,
                   int pshared)
{
    if (pshared != PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrier_init(pthread_barrier_t *restrict barrier,
             const pthread_barrierattr_t *restrict attr __unused,
             unsigned count)
{
    if (count == 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&barrier->mutex, 0) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pthread_cond_init(&barrier->cond, 0) < 0) {
        int errno_save = errno;
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&barrier->mutex);
        errno = errno_save;
        return -1;
    }

    barrier->limit = count;
    barrier->count = 0;
    barrier->phase = 0;

    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrier_destroy(pthread_barrier_t *barrier)
{
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&barrier->mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&barrier->cond);
    return 0;
}

int
pthread_barrier_wait(pthread_barrier_t *barrier)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier->mutex);
    barrier->count++;
    if (barrier->count >= barrier->limit) {
        barrier->phase++;
        barrier->count = 0;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&barrier->cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
        return PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD;
    } else {
        unsigned phase = barrier->phase;
        do
            pthread_cond_wait(&barrier->cond, &barrier->mutex);
        while (phase == barrier->phase);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
        return 0;
    }
}

#endif /* __APPLE__ */
```

Comment: Instead of `__unused`, why not just comment out the parameter name?

Comment: Because it's C, not C++. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776810/parameter-name-omitted-c-vs-c

Comment: Interesting, I work with both languages yet hadn't noticed this detail... Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3):

### No problems found

As they say, "no news is good news".  I read your code all the way through with an eye towards finding any possible errors, but I didn't find anything to criticize.

Instead I'll point out the things I liked about your code.

### Use of restrict keyword

I must admit, I don't use `restrict` but I should learn to, as it can only help the compiler.  I already advocate using `const` when appropriate, and this is similar.

### Proper error checking

You check for errors and set `errno` appropriately.

### Correct barrier operation

I tried to find any concurrency flaw in your barrier wait function but it looked correct.

### The one weird thing

The one thing I thought was strange was that you used a do {} while loop without the curly braces:

```
    do
        pthread_cond_wait(&barrier->cond, &barrier->mutex);
    while (phase == barrier->phase);
```

I've never seen that before but I guess if you like to do that it's fine.  I think people throw in the curlies because it doesn't waste any lines, whereas with a while loop or an if block it would add an extra line:

```
    while (condition) {
        foo();
    }                       // <-- Wasted line

    do {
        foo();
    } while (condition);    // <-- No waste
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this implementation suffers from the bug described here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13065

IOW, it's possible that a thread is accessing the barrier's memory while others have exit `pthread_barrier_wait`. And the threads having exited `pthread_barrier_wait` are free to call `pthread_barrier_destroy`, leading to undefined behavior.

The fix in glibc referred to in the ticket can be found here: https://github.com/Distrotech/glibc/commit/b02840bacdefde318d2ad2f920e50785b9b25d69